# Square a number but preserve the sign (in c)

Tags: c, math

Is there a simple way to preserve the sign after squaring a value. 
I currently have:

```
float signed_square(float x) {
    if (x > 0) {
        return x * x;
    } else {
        return -(x * x);
    }
}
```

Comment: but that makes no sense!! The square of a negative number IS positive!

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to get anything simpler. `(x * x) * (x / abs(x))`?

Comment: I don't understand either.

Comment: @Tommy I think you can get simpler: `x * abs(x)`

Comment: Basically you must somehow arrange to preserve the sign yourself, since there is no defined mathematical operation that will square the number and preserve the sign.  Either save it, do the square, then reapply it, or use one of the `abs` tricks above.  (Note that your original code is likely as efficient as any of the other approaches.)

Comment: (And, as stated elsewhere, your requirement doesn't make a lot of sense.)

Comment: I'm not going to join in with the other commenters and say that your requirement makes no sense. It's perfectly clear what you're trying to do. But I am curious why you want to do this particular thing. How is it useful? Incidentally, I see nothing wrong with the version in your question; using `fabs` IMHO doesn't improve it.

Comment: The reason for it I'm trying to make a AIS decoder and part of the specs it say " Sign of the field value should be preserved when squaring it, otherwise the left/right indication will be lost." ( http://catb.org/gpsd/AIVDM.html) I hope this clarifys why I would want to-do this.

Comment: I think @MitchWheat is right.

Comment: @KeithThompson Because of the identity `a<b <=> a|a|<b|b|` it's useful for comparisons where we only know `a` and `b^2` without taking the square root nor comparing if a < 0 first. I've used it a few times.

Answer (score 12):

As I said in the comments:

```
float signed_square(float x){
    return x * fabs(x);
}
```

Comment: Does that need to be `fabs()` or `fabsf()`?  Isn't `abs()` the integer function?

Comment: You're correct -- I incorrectly put my `C++` STL into my `C` mindset.

Comment: (+1), but should be `fabsf`.

Comment: I think the version in the question is more straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

C99 supplies `double copysign(double x, double y)`

> The `copysign` functions produce a value with the magnitude of `x` and the sign of `y`.

```
float signed_square(float x) {
  return copysignf(x*x, x);
}
```

Comment: @AaronFranke Performance varies by platforms and compiler - so no definitive performance assessment.  The heavy portion is the squaring and a good compiler is expected to see `x*x` and emit efficient code for it.  Consider trying the various approaches and see what performance you get.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is more simple. Multiply the number by it's absolute value (always being positive). So if the number starts off negative, then it's product with it's absolute value will also be negative.

Do this because you may, as I do, want to sum a series of areas above and below a curve.

Comment: How is this different from [the top existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27761633/298225).